# search Display Controller is Deprecated in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am getting the above warning message when trying to run my code.

```
NSDictionary *tempDictionary = nil;

    if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        tempDictionary = [filteredCompanyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else {
        tempDictionary= [self.client_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
```

It's been deprecated and did a google search but all I saw were tutorials in Swift.

I followed Ray Wenderlich tutorial here http://www.raywenderlich.com/16873/how-to-add-search-into-a-table-view but now i'm stuck.

```
#pragma mark Content Filtering
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array
    [self.filteredCompanyArray removeAllObjects];
    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
    filteredCompanyArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.client_list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: use UISearchController...check here...https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISearchController

Comment: I've changed (UISearchDisplayController *) to (UISearchController *) but still nothing. Please provide code sample

Comment: check this....http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift

Comment: You can better to use UISearchBar

Answer (score 14):

**The recipe below worked for me. I just successfully updated multiple scenarios of former iOS 7 code.**

Thanks also to the inspiration of [Updating to the iOS 8 Search Controller](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller/) and [Apple's API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchcontroller)

1. Remove UISearchDisplayDelegate protocol, add UISearchResultsUpdating and maybe UISearchControllerDelegate instead

```objective-c
@interface YOURTableviewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, /*UISearchDisplayDelegate, <- Removed*/ UISearchResultsUpdating /* Added */, UISearchControllerDelegate /* Added */>
{
```

2. Add new UISearchController as property:

```objective-c
// New property
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;

// ...

@implementation YOURTableviewController

@synthesize searchController; // New property
```

and initialize the new property in the didLoad method

```objective-c
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     // New code start -
     self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc]     initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
     self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
     self.searchController.delegate = self;
     self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

     self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

     self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
     [self.tableview setTableHeaderView:self.searchController.searchBar];
     self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
     // - New code end

     // Previous code
     //self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor orange]; 

     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

3. Add new UISearchResultsUpdating methods, update UISearchBarDelegate methods, and maybe add helping extra method like below, and maybe also UISearchControllerDelegate methods

```objective-c
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchResultsUpdating

- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)_searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = _searchController.searchBar.text;
    [self searchForText:searchString];
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchBarDelegate

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchController];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope
{
    [self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchController];
}

// Extra method
- (void)searchForText:(NSString *)searchString
{
    /* Put here everything that is in the method:
     - (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller     shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
     ...BUT WITH NO RETURN VALUE */
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchControllerDelegate

- (void)willPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    //..
}
- (void)didPresentSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    //..
}
- (void)willDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    //..
}
- (void)didDismissSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    //..
}
```

4. Replace and remove obsolete UISearchDisplayDelegate method(s)

```objective-c
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayDelegate

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString 
{ ... }
```

5. Replace 'searchDisplayController' everywhere with 'searchController'
6. Make replacements

Code like:

```objective-c
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

can be replaced with

```objective-c
if (self.searchController.isActive)
```

Code like:

```objective-c
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES];
```

can be replaced with

```objective-c
[self.searchController setActive:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

As `UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated, you need to use `UISearchController` for your purpose. Follow this link [Using UISearchController](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/)

Another link that might be useful for you [UISearchController Vs UISearchDisplayController](https://possiblemobile.com/2015/05/uisearchcontroller-vs-uisearchdisplaycontroller/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes UISearchDisplay Controller is deprecated, you should use UISearchController instead

Create Search Controller First

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;
```

Initialise Search controller properties

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
```

Bind Search controller with your table view

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
```

Implement UISearchResultUpdating delegate

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
 NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;
[self searchForText:searchString 
 scope:searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

You Can also use your filter method to filter result

Your search logic will go here

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
```

More detail you can find

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller/